# Delphi SDKtransform: many errors and missing classes in MacOS SDK

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have used `SDKtransform` for years (executed through "[SDK Transform Assistant](https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/tree/master/SDKTransformAssistant)") to implement the iOS and OSX frameworks that are not included with Delphi.

However, an increasing number of classes fail to be converted and are not included in the output .pas header file. Right now I need to convert `AVAudioEngine` from `AVFoundation` in MacOS 11 (Big Sur), but SDKtransform fails with a lot of these lines added to the log:

```
"WARN: cannot add ObjCInterface AVAudioEngine - base class unknown"
```

Could these be due to the way it is defined?

```
API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.10), ios(8.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0))
@interface AVAudioEngine : NSObject {
@private
    void *_impl;
}
- (instancetype)init;
- (void)attachNode:(AVAudioNode *)node;
- (void)detachNode:(AVAudioNode *)node;
...
@property (readonly, nonatomic) BOOL isInManualRenderingMode API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), watchos(4.0), tvos(11.0));
...
@end // AVAudioEngine
```

How do I autoconvert this type of header definitions?

Comment: Looks like that Git repo hasn't seen commits in over 5 years. A more up to date version appears to be hosted on BitBucket : https://bitbucket.org/JunHosokawa/sdktransformassistant/src/master/

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll have a look. However, this project only adds a GUI to SDKTransform.exe, which is included with Delphi, and the actual error messages I get is output from SDKTransform.

Comment: I tried the new version, but it doesn't seem to work. It calls SDKtransform, which returns immediately with instructions about its parameters. Looks like the current version of Transform Assistant is not in a running state? @Brian Have you been able to use it successfully?

Answer (score 2):

In the Delphi IDE: Go to Tools -> Options -> Deployment -> SDK Manager. Select the macOSX sdk. Click on the "New" button in order to add a new remote path item. Add `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/objc` with "File Mask" `*` and "Path type" `Include Path`. Close the dialog. Click "Update Local File Cache".

This will add the headers for NSObject.